# TTPhotoViewController remove toolbar and block tab bar item title change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, three20

I am using TTPhotoViewController to show several images from the net.
I have shiny black styled application with customized tab bar (image is drawn over all tab bar layers). When TTPhotoViewController appears on the screen it adds blue toolbar above my tab bar. How can I remove it or prevent showing? `self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = YES;`
 doesn't work for me.

Another question is how I can keep TTPhotoViewController silent? It draws current photo file name instead of my current uitabbaritem title which makes Apple's overlay appear over my customized tab bar image layer.

---

upd: Found way to hide toolbar forever:  just commented out toolbar-related code from `TTPhotoViewController.m` in  `-(void)loadView` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found way to hide toolbar forever: just commented out toolbar-related code from `TTPhotoViewController.m` in `- (void)loadView` method.

Also found that uitabbaritem.title changes automatically if self.title was changed, so simply comment out changes to `self.title` in `- (void)updateChrome` method too.